# SQL query, where name in column begins with a certain letter; clarification

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a vb.net application running a process. In order to speed it up I have split it into several threads, the process asks for employees in groups of names as below.

```
 SELECT * FROM Employ WHERE Name like '[A-C]%' ORDER BY RDate DESC
```

Mostly I have groups like 'A-C' and so on, but it just so happens that the 'Ms' are the biggest group, so I made them their own group, 'M-M' and even that is not enough, their thread takes way too long to finish. So I would like to make 2 groups like this 'Ma-Mm' and 'Mn-Mz'.

Is it just a case of changing the above query to those letters? like:

```
SELECT * FROM Employ WHERE Name like '[Ma-Mm]%' ORDER BY RDate DESC
SELECT * FROM Employ WHERE Name like '[Mn-Mz]%' ORDER BY RDate DESC
```

Also providing that that name column is indexed, is this the most optimal way to write that query?

Edit: I am using Ms SQL Server

Comment: I don't think pattern matching works like that. Do you need to order at this level? That's a potential bottleneck.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use a Full Text Search index. (*I am assuming you are using Sql Server*)

Comment: Yep I tested, pattern matching *definitely* doesn't work like that. At least in SQL Server. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df6cc/1

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I checked the order by, and there is no discernible difference over the execution time of the entire process, with or with out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do:

```
WHERE Name like 'M[a-m]%'
```

However, a generate range, such as My-No, would be harder to express.  You can always do:

```
WHERE name >= 'Ma' and name < 'Mn'
```

as well.  This works for more complex ranges.

Comment: I used this, "WHERE Name like 'M[a-m]%'", it passed the count test, so picked all relevant columns, greatly appreciate the help.